# Bookshelf.js, update after fetchAll() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

Using bookshelf.js, I'm trying to get a set of objects and then update them all.

```
function markPostsAsSent(postsIds) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Get posts
        Search.Post
        .where({ id: postsIds })
        .fetchAll()
        .then(posts => {
            // For each post, update sent value
            Promise.map(posts.toJSON(), post => post.save({ is_sent: true }))
            .then(() => {
                resolve(true);
            }, err => {
                reject(Dependencies.getException(exceptionName, 500, 'POST_UPDATE_ERROR', new Error(), err));
            });
        }, err => {
            reject(Dependencies.getException(exceptionName, 500, 'POST_FETCH_ERROR', new Error(), err));
        });
    });
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve in Bookshelf.js is equivalent to this in SQL :

```
UPDATE searches_posts
SET is_sent = true
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

`(1, 2, 3, 4)` are obviously values from `postsIds` parameter.

The SQL seems so much more simpler than the Bookshelf.js method.

Is there a better way to update these rows all at the same time instead of looping on .save() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems solid, but of course, there is a better way. 
E.g., you can specify explicitly that you want to perform an update (http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-save) and you can tap into the knex query builder and limit which entries you want to update (http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereIn).

So, putting everything together, try something like this (this is some demo example I performed in order to test the solution):

```
new Person().query(function(qb) {
    qb.whereIn('id', [2, 4]);
}).save({
    number_of_children: 5
}, {
    method: 'update'
}).then(function() {
    //Entries with ids 2 and 4 have been updated!
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What about update/insert? What is more eloquent way to do this?

```
yield Promise.map data, (oneEvent)->
  eventModel = new Event oneEvent

  eventModel.fetch().then (fromDB) ->
    return do eventModel.save if not fromDB?
    fromDB.save oneEvent
```

Comment: Is this ES6 compatible ?